# Procedures for inserting values into table causes error after Migrated from SQL Server 2008 to Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2008-r2, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

The following is the SQL Server 2008s stored procedure I have:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[stp_InsertAboutUs]  
    @Text text  
    ,@Image varchar(500)  
    ,@CreatedBy uniqueidentifier  
    ,@ModifiedBy uniqueidentifier  
    ,@EntityId uniqueidentifier  
AS  
BEGIN  
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
    SET NOCOUNT ON;             

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[AboutUS]([Text], [Image], [CreatedOn], 
                                [ModifiedOn], [CreatedBy], [ModifiedBy], [EntityId])  
    OUTPUT inserted.Id  
    VALUES (@Text, @Image, getdate(), getdate(), @CreatedBy, @ModifiedBy, @EntityId)
END
```

Which is working good, But somehow after I migrated this code to Oracle 12c using the inbuilt SQL Developer, the procedure seems weird and it is as follows:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE stp_InsertAboutUs
(
  v_Text IN CLOB DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_Image IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_CreatedBy IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_ModifiedBy IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_EntityId IN CHAR DEFAULT NULL 
)
AS
   v_temp INTO_%ROWTYPE;
   cv_ins SYS_REFCURSOR;    
BEGIN    
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
--Why the below code here??
   AboutUS(TEXT,
           IMAGE,
           CreatedOn,
           ModifiedOn,
           CreatedBy,
           ModifiedBy,
           EntityId) ;
   LOOP
      FETCH cv_ins INTO v_temp;
      EXIT WHEN cv_ins%NOTFOUND;
      INSERT INTO INTO_ VALUES v_temp; -- What is INTO_ means?? 
   END LOOP;
   CLOSE cv_ins;
   OUTPUT(INSERTED.Id) ;
   VALUES_(v_Text,
           v_Image,
           SYSDATE,
           SYSDATE,
           v_CreatedBy,
           v_ModifiedBy,
           v_EntityId) ;
END;
```

Why does this happen, remaining all the procedures were migrated correctly except the procedures which have an Insert statement in them went wrong. Also, what is the alternate solution for the above oracle procedure to make it work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering Your quersion what is the alternate solution for the above oracle procedure to make it work?
Try this procedure, where I'm assuming You have ID column in the AboutUs table. If the column name is differs You should replace with the proper one.

```
create or replace procedure stp_InsertAboutUs(v_Text in clob default null,
                                              v_Image in varchar2 default null,
                                              v_CreatedBy in char default null,
                                              v_ModifiedBy in char default null,
                                              v_EntityId in char default null) as
   v_InsertedID AboutUs.Id%type;    
begin
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   insert into AboutUS
      (Text, Image, CreatedOn, ModifiedOn, CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, EntityId)
   values
      (v_Text, v_Image, sysdate, sysdate, v_CreatedBy, v_ModifiedBy, v_EntityId)
   returning ID into v_InsertedID;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_InsertedID);
end;
```

For the second question, i.e Why does this happen - I don't know, never tried the inbuilt functionality of SQL Developer to migrate the databases.

Comment: Thanks for the response.But do u know any reason why this migration created problem for procedures that have insert statements in them?
Thanks for the alternate solution,I did the same.